# Comparing Color in java

Tags: java, colors, awt, awtrobot

NOTE: `robot.getcolor(int i, int j)` is simply  `return robot.getPixelColor(i,j);`

```
void test2(int i, int j)
{
    System.out.println(robot.getcolor(i,j));
    Color a = robot.getcolor(i,j);
    Color b  = new Color(91,108,201);
    if(a == b)
    {
        System.out.println("success!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("FAILURE");
    }
}
```

If I do that, then I get this outprint:

> java.awt.Color[r=91,g=108,b=201]
>
> FAILURE

What I already tested:

- Comparing two colors with == works.
- The Alpha parameter shouldn't be a problem, since its 255 and if I add it into the new Color(91,108,201,255) it still prints out FAILURE.

Comment: `a.equals(b)`, perhaps?

Comment: It was answered 5 years ago here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761117/testing-if-colors-equal
(0:

Answer (score 3):

Try changing line 6 to something like `if(a.equals(b)) {`.

`==` compares if two objects are the same object 
`.equals()` compares if two objects are equivalent (as defined by that specific class) 
Check out [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/12/difference-between-equals-method-and-equality-operator-java.html) for more info

Comment: You are my hero! THANK YOU!

Comment: you're welcome, an upvote is always an appreciated reward for help!

Comment: My upvotes arent public jet :( i need 15 reputation they told me (first question)

Comment: @ Leon Mächler I up voted @beartech1 answer on your behalf (0:

Comment: @LeonMächler: While not being able to upvote, you can accept the answer if it solves your problem (click the check mark below the vote-arrows)

Comment: any action on this @user5239761?